# React Native Push Notification with Amazon SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns

Can someone point me in the direction of a codebase or tutorial that shows you how to implement Push Notification in a React Native project using Amazon SNS?

I've been struggling with the documentation for about a week. Im able to register devices within Amazon SNS but messages are not being received. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

All my code is in App.js. Thanks in advance!

```
    import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
    import { useEffect } from "react";
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from "react-native";
    import AWS from "aws-sdk";
    import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
    import {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    REGION,
    TOPIC_ARN,
    PLATFORM_ARN,
    IOS_PLATFORM_ARN,
    EXPO_PROJECT_ID,
    } from "@env";
    export default function App() {
    useEffect(() => {
    // Request permission to receive notifications
    const requestUserPermission = async () => {
    const { status } = await Notifications.requestPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== "granted") {
    console.log("Permission to receive notifications was denied.");
    }
    };
    // Register device token with AWS SNS
    const registerDeviceTokenWithSNS = async () => {
    try {
    const deviceToken = (
    await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync({
    projectId: EXPO_PROJECT_ID,
    })
    ).data;
    // Configure AWS SDK
    AWS.config.update({
    region: REGION,
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    });
    const SNS = new AWS.SNS({ correctClockSkew: true });
    const platformApplicationArn = PLATFORM_ARN; // ARN of your platform application in AWS SNS
    // Create platform endpoint and subscribe to topic
    const endpointParams = {
    PlatformApplicationArn: platformApplicationArn,
    Token: deviceToken,
    };
    const createEndpointResponse = await SNS.createPlatformEndpoint(
    endpointParams
    ).promise();
    const endpointArn = createEndpointResponse.EndpointArn;
    const subscribeParams = {
    TopicArn: TOPIC_ARN, // ARN of the topic you want to subscribe to
    Protocol: "Application",
    Endpoint: endpointArn,
    };
    await SNS.subscribe(subscribeParams).promise();
    console.log("Successfully registered device with AWS SNS.");
    } catch (error) {
    console.log("Failed to register device with AWS SNS:", error);
    }
    };
    requestUserPermission();
    registerDeviceTokenWithSNS();
    }, []);
    return (
    
    <View style={styles.container}> <Text>AWS SNS Demo</Text> <StatusBar style="auto" /> </View> ); } const styles = StyleSheet.*create*({ container: { flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#fff", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", }, });
```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to find an article/blog/document for this? I am also trying to use AWS SNS to send push notifications to users, the backend I am using is Spring Boot based. Any good resource that I can follow to send push notifs to users?

Comment: @suyashghuge Hi... So I am still struggling with this honestly but I've found a few articles: https://notaday3.medium.com/react-native-push-notifications-with-amazon-sns-b244c7047d0f

Comment: @suyashghuge also this one: https://zhijunchen.com/mobile-push-notification-overview-using-aws-sns-and-react-native/

Comment: Thank you so much! :) If I find something, or if I'm able to crack this, I will post here!

Comment: @suyashghuge Hi do you still need help? I was able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to figure this out on my own. What I didn't realize is that in order to get Amazon SNS to work you have to be running at least a development build on your actual device. Once I built the apk and ipa files that I needed for android and ios it worked. If anyone needs help with Amazon SNS with React Native just reply to this and I will try to help.

Comment: Did you need to supply an accessServerKey when running `serviceWorker.pushManager.subscribe` ? It requires that variable in Chrome to pass correctly.